# LDAP User Management Tool for Mac 10.7.1

Tags: linux, mac-osx, ldap

I have been using Luma on Linux to create and manage LDAP user accounts. I've now a macbook  pro, and am looking for an equivalent program for Macosx - something that will automatically and correctly generate new uidNumber and gidNumber attributes when creating a new inetOrgPerson.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several tools. You might want to check out:

[Apache Directory Server/Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) - an LDAP browser and directory client for Linux, Mac OS X, and Microsoft Windows, and as a plug-in for the Eclipse development environment.

[JXplorer](http://jxplorer.org/) - A Java-based browser that runs in any operating environment.

[LDAP Account Manager](http://www.ldap-account-manager.org/) - A PHP based webfrontend for managing various account types in an LDAP directory.

[phpLDAPadmin](http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) - A web-based LDAP administration tool for creating and editing LDAP entries in any LDAP server.

I have had the most luck with [phpLDAPadmin](http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). Its the easiest to use but requires some time to setup. It all depends how in depth your needs are.

Comment: I love Apache Directory Studio, however, I have not found a way to make it automatically increment `uidNumber` and `gidNumber` when creating a new `inetOrgPerson` object. So that's something OP should keep in mind.

Comment: Yes, Apache Directory Studios is by far my favorite of those mentioned, however there does seem to be no auto-increment function, so I'm going with phpLDAPadmin for now.